# Python C API: How to get something from a module

Tags: python, python-c-api

In Python C API, I already know how to import a module via `PyImport_ImportModule`, as described in [Python Documentation: Importing Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html). I also know that there is a lot of ways to create or allocate or initialize a module and some functions for operating a module, as described in [Python Documentation: Module Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#support-functions).

But how can I get a function from a module (and call it), or, get a type/class from a module (and instantiate it), or, get an object from a module (and operate on it), or get anything from a module and do anything I want to do?

I think this can be a fool question but I really cannot find any tutorial or documentation. The only way I think that I can achieve this is use `PyModule_GetDict` to get the `__dict__` property of the module and fetch what I want, as described in [the latter documentation I mentioned](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html). But the documentation also recommend that one should not use this function to operate the module.

So any "official way" or best practice for getting something from a module?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation for `PyModule_GetDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_GetDict):

> It is recommended extensions use other `PyModule_*()` and `PyObject_*()` functions rather than directly manipulate a module’s `__dict__`.

The functions you need are generic object functions (`PyObject_*`) rather than module functions (`PyModule_*`), and I suspect this is where you were looking in the wrong place.

You want to use [`PyObject_GetAttr`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttr) or [`PyObject_GetAttrString`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttrString).